# SSIS package not executing Script Task when called from C# web form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ssis

I have a C# web form built in Visual Studio that calls a SSIS package. The first step in the SSIS package is a Script Tasks that unzips a file. It then deletes data in some tables in SQL Server and then inserts data back into those tables from the contents of the .zip file. When the package is run in VS, it completes successfully without any issues. When I call the package from the C# form, it will not run the Script Task but doesn't throw any errors.

Here is my code that calls the SSIS package:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime; // SSIS Package Execution

namespace LoadZip
{
    public class ExecuteSSIS
    {
        public void exePackage(string tbFilePath, string server)
        {
            String pkgLocation = @"C:\SSIS.dtsx";
            Package ssisPackage;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult result;
            Variables vars;

            app = new Application();
            ssisPackage = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation,null);

            vars = ssisPackage.Variables;
            vars["sqlServerName"].Value = server; Console.WriteLine("var server = " + server);
            vars["filenameWithPath"].Value = tbFilePath; Console.WriteLine("var tbFilePath = " + tbFilePath);

            result = ssisPackage.Execute();

            if (result == DTSExecResult.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("SSIS Package Successfully Executed");
            else if (result == DTSExecResult.Failure)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("********** SSIS PACKAGE FAILED **********");
                foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in ssisPackage.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(local_DtsError.Description);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("********** END FAILED REPORT **********");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the SSIS package looks like:

[image: SSIS Package]

As I mentioned, when I run the package from my C# form, I get returned "SSIS Package Successfully Executed" but it really does not run it. Instead it seems to "fail" at the Script Task and not execute the rest of the package.

If I disable the Script Task (UnZip File) and re-run the SSIS package from my C# form, the package executes successfully. So I know my form is hitting the package and passing along the variables, but it just doesn't seem to like the script task although when executed outside the form, it works just fine.

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4cd6b488-c10c-47f2-8235-7ddaca5243a2/how-do-i-execute-a-dtsx-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: SQLCMD.EXE is a command line utility that comes with SQL Server and can be run with the Net class Process.  So you can run the dtsx using sqlcmd.exe.  See : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29059831/how-to-use-sqlcmd-to-run-a-dtsx-package.html

Comment: I'm familiar with the sqlcmd.exe as I've used it in stored procedures, but I'm very new to C#. I'm guessing the sqlcmd.exe will replace my code above? If so, how do I go about implementing that? Also, can I pass my variables, "sqlServerName" and "filenameWithPath" to my package with sqlcmd.exe?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8.  The server name and path are part of the command line parameters (start info).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It sounds like the Script Task within the Package is the culprit. I wonder if something in there is attempting to interact with the UI. The other option is that there is something in the Script Task that has a dependency that is satisfied on your machine but not in the context of the web service invocation.